# Is it possible to still use rtweet R package to retrieve tweets from Twitter

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

I have made an app that retrieves tweets using the function rweet::get_timeline (in the rtweet package).

The app suddenly stopped working with the following error message:

> Warning: Error in : Twitter API failed [403]. Check error message at
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting
>
> - You currently have access to Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need
>   a different access level. You can learn more here:
>   https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve
>   (453)

According to one Twitter page, the free tier does not seem to allow tweet pulls (see screenshot below).

Just to have this perfectly clear: Does this mean that it will now longer be possible to use rtweet::get_timeline (to retrieve tweets from different users)? Thanks for any information that might help clarify this!

[image: Screenshot from Twitter page describing the API functionalities available under the free and paid versions]

Comment: Only the paid tier of Twitter API can use search-related methods, therefore rtweet::get_timeline no longer works. Rtweet appears to be for the most part dead now. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: If you have a university affiliation, the access actually got better recently.  A free academic developer account works a lot like a paid tier account.

Comment: You may also want to see this blog post written by the package maintainer about the future of {rtweet}: https://llrs.dev/post/2023/02/16/rtweet-future/